# How does JavaScript hook WinRT events?

Tags: javascript, events, interop, windows-8, windows-runtime

Suppose I'm writing a WinRT app with both JavaScript and C# code, and I want my JavaScript code to hook an event on my C# object.

I know that's supposed to be possible, but what would that JavaScript code look like? How are events (however the concept of a CLR event is represented in WinRT) exposed in the JavaScript projection?

If a concrete example would help, let's say my C# object has this event:

```
public event EventHandler Initialized;
```

How do I hook that event from JavaScript?

(I'm sure the answer is buried in one of the [//build/ videos](http://www.buildwindows.com/Sessions), but they're not exactly searchable.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you have your C# class hooked up and accessible from JavaScript (see [C# //Build/ talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-531T) for details), it should be as simple as this:

```
var foo = new CSharpClass();
foo.addEventListener("Initialized", onInitialized);
```

Then when C# fires the event, your onInitialized function will be called.

Comment: Cool. What's the signature for the JavaScript method? Does it take sender and EventArgs, or is it parameterless since it's just an EventArgs with no payload?

Comment: It takes 1 argument which is an object containing the sender and the event arguments.

Comment: Some more on JavaScript events can be seen in the JavaScript //build/ talk at 24:00.  http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-533T